# What does "disjoint" here means?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In what aspects are the Opponents disjointed? The team they followed?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here, 'disjointed' refers to how well the opposing team played; a team that plays well is said to be 'cohesive' (to have worked together), and 'disjointed' here means they... didn't.